# Testes unitários no Android

Tags: android, testes-de-unidade

Como fazer teste unitário no Android?

Até onde pesquisei só é possível utilizar o *framework* [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials).

Existe outra maneira de fazer teste unitário no Android?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem várias opções dependendo do que você quer fazer.

Você pode dividir seus testes em dois tipos:

- Unitários
- Funcionais

E tem duas opções de onde executar eles:

- Dalvik (Dentro do aparelho)
- JVM (Dentro da sua maquina)

Os testes Unitários focam no teste de uma unidade isolada, normalmente uma classe. Já os testes funcionais testam varias unidades de código e/ou testes de inicio ou fim de uma funcionalidade.

O `Android` vem com uma extensão do `JUnit` versão 3. E você pode olhar a documentação padrão [aqui.](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)
Estes testes rodam dentro do emulador/aparelho e podem demorar um pouco mais para executar.

O `Robotim` é um framework que facilita a criação de testes funcionais dentro da Dalvik.

Existe também o `Roboletric` que simula o ambiente do android dentro da JVM e por rodar no desktop é muito mais rápido.

Existem o `UIAutomator` que é padrão do android para versões 4.1 e superiores. Você pode utilizar ele quando quiser acessar varias aplicações por exemplo um aplicativo que utiliza fotos tiradas pela Câmera.

Outra opção para testes é o `Monkey` que realiza eventos randômicos na sua aplicação, muito útil para testar se todas as telas estão ok e fazer testes de stress no aplicativo.

Existem algumas outra bibliotecas mas estas são as mais conhecidas e acredito que se encaixam na maioria dos problemas para testar sua aplicação.

Existe um ótimo artigo de referencia no site [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html) que cobre varios casos e quando utilizar um ou outro.